# What is the impact of declaring a method as final?

Tags: java, oop

Can  method declared as final be overridden and overloading ?
2 if A is static sub class of B. how to access a method in  class A ??

Comment: no - if it is final, then no. You only do it if you know no aspect of that method will require changing.

Comment: you mean NO overridden and overloading..

Comment: "No overriding" - You can overload it because overloading means keep the name, linkage scope, and return type same - but the args and the definition body `{}` will be different. Overriding works during runtime as opposed to overloading which happens compile-time. See [this](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/difference-between-method-overloading-and-overriding-in-java/). Definitely NO OVERRIDING.

Comment: Do you mean "overridden and overloaded"? Or do you mean "overridden *or* overloaded"

Answer (score 5):

You **can** overload a method declared `final`. (An overloaded method is fundamentally a completely different function, akin to a function having a different name).

You **cannot** override a method declared `final`.